# How to access subdirectory inside of Jenkins ${workspace}/?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've been trying to **access a subdirectory inside of my Jenkins workspace** with unix command :  `sh "cd ${workspace}/Myfolder"`, however the command does not work. I am using groovy script in Jenkins (Jenkinsfile).

My `${workspace}` directory is: `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_sam_single_pipeline`

When I execute command: `sh "cd ${workspace}/Myfolder"`

I use command: `sh "pwd"`

The output is:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_sam_single_pipeline
```

It seems I cannot access "Myfolder" subdirectory by using the "cd" command.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in declarative pipeline you can use

```
dir('MyFolder') {
    sh "pwd"
}
```

or use one shell for all your commands

```
sh """
  cd MyFolder
  pwd 
"""
```

or join commands

```
  sh "cd MyFolder && pwd"
```

Comment: That is exactly the answer. I also asked someone from my work and they came up with same answer!!! Great thanks ,

Comment: The last 2 options will only work by themselves, once they are done the shell returns to the WORKSPACE dir...